# How to Fetch API that returning result with the same order as first parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

Is there a way to return the result from fetch API with the same order *req.body*, the result return a random order

```
exports.bookData = async (req, res) => {
  let inputList = req.body.isbns;
  let bookData = [];
  let price = [];
  let shipping = [];
  let headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: "6456_46446548498465",
  };

  let url = `https://api1/${inputList}`;
 
  await fetch(url, { headers: headers })
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
              // calculate
        return response.json();
      }
    })
    .then((json) => {
      if (json) {
        bookData.push(json);
      } 
    });
     await fetch(
      `https://api3.com/${inputList}/6465dc68-564h5466g-546f684g86/`
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
  let result = {
    bookData,
    price,
    shipping
  };

  return res.json(result);
};
```

**Isbns :**
2935689888, 2856989845, 1156464654

**output:**

bookData: [ { book: [Object] } ],
{
price: '$11.54',
link: 'https://api/2856989845',
},

bookData: [ { book: [Object] } ],
{
price: '$15.54',
link: 'https://api/2935689888',
},

bookData: [ { book: [Object] } ],
{
price: '$05.54',
link: 'https://api/1156464654',
},

**output: should be **

bookData: [ { book: [Object] } ],
{
price: '$15.54',
link: 'https://api/2935689888',
},

bookData: [ { book: [Object] } ],
{
price: '$11.54',
link: 'https://api/2856989845',
},

bookData: [ { book: [Object] } ],
{
price: '$05.54',
link: 'https://api/1156464654',
},

Comment: This should be organized from the backend API.

Comment: However, you can sort them out because the isbn appears at the end of each item.

Comment: Are you saying you're making a single request, with 3 ISBNs in a parameter, and it returns an array of books? What is this api?

Comment: Why is `bookData` an array of zero or one items? Why are you only logging the result of the second request but never do anything else with it?